# How much BTU increase would there be from adding "fins" to hot water pipe (Baseboard Heat)?

Tags: water-heater

Wasn't sure if this site or Engineering would be a better fit. Chose here.

My baseboard heat pipe (in 1 room) has no fins. From looking [here](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/copper-pipe-heat-loss-d_19.html), it looks like a 3/4" uninsulated copper pipe at 100 °F will dissipate 60 BTU / hr ft. If "fins" are added, for instance [these](https://www.homedepot.com/p/FabTek-Logic-Fin-Clamp-Baseboard-Element-for-3-4-in-Copper-Baseboard-Piping-1-ft-Section-FCL-75CX1FT/300641178), which claim 591 BTU / hr ft (but no temperature given) do I really get an increase of 531 BTU / ft hr (give or take based on temperature)?

Comment: Remember that heat extracted one place is not available in another place. A baseboard system has to be designed and balanced to heat evenly through the house, and extracting more heat from the same volume of water means the boiler has to work harder to keep up. This isn't free energy, it's a way of shifting where the energy goes.

Comment: On the other hand, it is claimed that systems which extract heat from water going down the drain, where it _would_ be thrown away otherwise, can be helpful. I haven't seen solid numbers on that, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going directly to the [manufacturer's website](http://www.finclampelement.com/Certifications), they give the test conditions. The 3/4" copper pipe is running 180F water at 1 GPM to get 591 BTU/hr per foot. So to know how much of an increase you get, you need numbers for bare pipe at 180F instead of 100F.

If real world experience means anything, fins vs no fins is like heat vs no heat. I have a 20 foot run of baseboard in a room where the first 10 feet contains pipe with no fins and the second 10 feet contains a normal finned pipe. For the part with no fins, you can tell there's a warm pipe in there but that section produces essentially no effective heat. Right next to it, the part with fins produces heat like gangbusters with enough convective air currents to make sheer curtains move above it. My water temp is 175F.